# How to access package contents such Photos through Bash?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, package, cd

I want to do something like this:

```
alias pictures='cd ~/Pictures/Photos.photoslibrary/Master'
```

However, `Photos.photoslibrary` is a package whose contents can be viewed in Finder. Can I change directory to the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a normal directory. Try:

```
ls -l ~/Pictures/Photos.photoslibrary
```

to see what is inside.